# Google Places API Quota Exceeded

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, request, google-places-api

I recently created an iOS app in which I would like to use Google Places API to get information about a restaurant that a user has searched. However, after my first request, the API keeps saying that my daily quota is exceeded. In the screenshot below, the requests per day are limited to 1, but the requests per 100 seconds can be up to 10,000, which doesn't make sense to me.

[image]

Here is my Swift code for calling the API (after initializing the API in AppDelegate.swift):

```
let client = GMSPlacesClient.shared()
client.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    print("Current Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return
  }


  if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
    let place = placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
    if let place = place {
        print(place.name)
        print(place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
        .joined(separator: "\n"))
    }
  }
})
```

Am I only allowed 1 Places request unless I put in my billing information, or is there something I should change to allow for more requests?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use and billing of a third-party service and not about programming.

Comment: One request sounds right if you haven't enabled billing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use and billing of a third-party service and not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's related to your billing account.
The issue is because you haven't created the billing account for your project.
Without billing account by default good maps API will allow only 1 request per key per day.

Answer (score -1):

Before you can use Google Maps Platform [Places SDK for IOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start), you need to use an **API key** in your code. You can follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/get-api-key) to generate an API key. You must also have a **valid billing account linked in the project** where your API key was. Here is a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uINleRduCWM) of how you can create and attach a billing account in your project. You must always check these things for this kind of error.